# How to compare input to array php

Tags: php

I am making an opposites quiz. The idea is when prompted with a word. You must reply with the opposite. I have made two arrays with word lists and a set of predefined example questions to ask. The idea is that I will compare the word to an opposite and it will keep going until it finds the correct one for the input.

For some reason it is not working. I'm fairly new to PHP and I am sure there is an easier way to do this. For now this is what I have to work with.

Also I want to do this with arrays, not with MySQL

```
    <?php
    $wl1 = array('Hot', 'Summer', 'Hard', 'Dry', 'Simple', 'Light', 'Weak', 'Male', 'Sad', 'Win', 'Small', 'Ignore', 'Buy', 'Succeed', 'Reject', 'Prevent',
    'Exclude');
    $wl2 = array('Cold', 'Winter', 'Soft', 'Wet', 'Complex', 'Darkness', 'Strong', 'Female', 'Happy', 'Lose', 'Big', 'Pay Attention', 'Sell', 'Fail', 'Accept',
    'Allow', 'Include');

    $compl = array("Hot is to cold",
                   "Summer is to winter",
                   "Hard is to soft",
                   "Dry is to wet",
                   "Simple is to complex",
                   "Light is to darkness",
                   "Weak is to strong",
                   "Male is to female",
                   "Sad is to happy",
                   "Win is to lose",
                   "Small is to big",
                   "Ignore is to pay attention",
                   "Buy is to sell",
                   "Succeed is to fail",
                   "Reject is to accept",
                   "Prevent is to allow",
                   "Exclude is to include");

    $complr = $compl[array_rand($compl)];
    $wl2r = $wl2[array_rand($wl1)];
    $q = $complr . " as ".$wl2r." is to "."<br>";
    echo $q;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $score = 0;
        $answer = $_POST['answer'];
            if($wl2r == "Cold" && $answer == "Hot"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Winter" && $answer == "Summer"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Soft" && $answer == "Hard"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Wet" && $answer == "Dry"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Complex" && $answer == "Simple"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Darkness" && $answer == "Light"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Strong" && $answer == "Weak"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Female" && $answer == "Male"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Happy" && $answer == "Sad"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Lose" && $answer == "Win"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Big" && $answer == "Small"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Pay Attention" && $answer == "Ignore"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Sell" && $answer == "Buy"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Fail" && $answer == "Succeed"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Accept" && $answer == "Reject"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Allow" && $answer == "Prevent"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
            if($wl2r == "Include" && $answer == "Exclude"){
                echo "Correct";
                $score++;
            }
        echo $score;


    }







?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Opposites</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="task3.php" method="post">
            Enter your Answer <input type="text" name="answer">
            <input type="submit" name='submit'>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem is that without a database, it's not possible to persist your program's  needed state data between page loads. For example, after a submission, there's no way to know which random selection had been made on the previous page load or what the score was. The best way to do this is with a database or Ajax, but short of that, it's possible (but not very elegant) to pass data along without much effort using hidden input fields. You can also explore local storage and JavaScript which won't be quite so hacky.

As for your game logic, consider using an associative array. Instead of the array keys being a numerical sequence 0, 1, 2..., use the first pair's string as the key to retrieve its partner. This eliminates the huge conditional block, a lot of typing and possible bugs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Opposites</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<?php
$compliments = [
    'Hot' => 'Cold',
    'Summer' => 'Winter',
    'Hard' => 'Soft',
    'Dry' => 'Wet',
    'Simple' => 'Complex',
    'Light' => 'Dark',
    'Weak' => 'Strong',
    'Male' => 'Female',
    'Sad' => 'Happy',
    'Win' => 'Lose',
    'Small' => 'Big',
    'Ignore' => 'Pay Attention',
    'Buy' => 'Sell',
    'Succeed' => 'Fail',
    'Reject' => 'Accept',
    'Prevent' => 'Allow',
    'Exclude' => 'Include'
];
$score = isset($_POST['score']) ? (int)$_POST['score'] : 0;

if (isset($_POST['answer']) && isset($_POST['question'])) {
    if ($_POST['answer'] === $compliments[$_POST['question']]) {
        echo "<div>Correct, " . $_POST['question'] . " is to " . $_POST['answer'] . ".</div>";
        $score++;
    }
    else {
        echo "<div>Incorrect. " . $_POST['question'] . " is to " . 
             $compliments[$_POST['question']] . ", not to " . $_POST['answer'] . ".</div>";
    }
}

$sample = array_rand($compliments);
$test = array_rand($compliments);
echo "<div>Score: $score</div>";
echo "<div>$compliments[$sample] is to $sample as $test is to </div>";
?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="task3.php" method="post">
            Enter your Answer <input type="text" name="answer">
            <input type="hidden" name="question" value="<?= isset($test) ? $test : "" ?>"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="score" value="<?= isset($score) ? $score: "" ?>"></input>
            <input type="submit" name='submit'>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally, if you ever want to access the reversed array, e.g. look up `'Cold'` to get `'Hot'`, use [array_flip](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php).

Comment: I tried that, and it just always showed up with Incorrect. How does it know if it is the correct one or not?

Comment: Did you test it by hard coding in test values? `$test = 'Ignore'; $answer = 'Pay Attention';` will evaluate as true. Correct values are determined by keying into the array. `$compliments['Hot'] === 'Cold'` for example, is true, while `$compliments['Small'] === 'Pay Attention'` is not (imagine these literal strings as your variables).

Comment: Yes the Hard code works, just puzzled as to why it doesnt work on its own

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that--you'll need to show a specific example. Since I've hard-coded a random answer in my test suite, there is only a 1 in 17 chance you'll see `"Correct"`. Try it in your web app and let me know if it still doesn't work, or use `readline` to enter input on the CLI. Watch out for case sensitivity and use `strtolower` on both strings to ignore case.

Comment: I think we have misunderstood each other. When the word "Include" comes up for example, if you insert the word "Exclude" it would say correct, if you put the word "Sad" for example, it will say "incorrect". I don't want it to have a chance of being right.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on what you're asking then. If you never want your user to have a chance of being right, just print `"Incorrect"` always and you're done, no?

Comment: When they insert the correct opposite, it says correct, when they input the incorrect opposite, it says incorrect. But the example you have provided seems to not be working. But looks more effective than the one I made lol

Comment: Right, and that's not what you want? That's precisely what this program does. What isn't working about it?

Comment: The program is displaying incorrect, even when it is correct

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the **test example** as the behavior in the final code. In the above code, `$_POST['answer']` is used rather than a hard coded value. I added `readline` to the CLI example so it will behave like the final result. I assumed you'd understand the distinction.

Comment: I'm an Idiot and still don't understand. How do I make it work ;-;

Comment: That's OK. If you go to https://repl.it/repls/WoodenRichNewsaggregator and press the Run button, then type your answer in, does it behave as you wish? I can't easily just send you to a .php page link, it's a command line program to test the code logic. But the full `<?php ... ?>` example above should work on your server, or localhost, or wherever you're serving your .php page from.

Comment: That works exactly how I want it to. However, it does not work if I put it into my code and run it. It just does this and still returns incorrect https://gyazo.com/9ab93ade39db3e020c2f897ebbebd6ca

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is from your image; sorry. Are you using the code provided above, or the command line code? BTW, you won't be able to persist `$score` across page loads. You'll need a database or a trick like sending it through the POST request to persist that data (or use JS for your game).

Comment: The score thing is fine, I am using the CLI code and it still just shows "incorrect" but at the end of the first sentence for some reason

Comment: If you're serving your .php page, don't use my command line interface code. That's just for testing! It's the same *logic*, but if you want to serve a webpage, use the code I posted in the answer. I think you should only `echo` the question if there's not an answer provided. That's up to your page design. I'll repost the code, but it may not be your desired layout.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I see what's going on here. None of the data is being persisted through the page load. I'll update the answer.

Comment: You still there?

Comment: Yep, posting an update. Sorry for the confusion--I fired up WAMP and got it working as you're most likely intending!

Comment: Okay no problem, just take your time :)

Comment: You are honestly the best person I've met on the internet. Its only a small thing but the fact that you have persisted with a silly person like me. The program works perfectly and more! I cannot appriciate your help enough

Comment: No sweat, glad it worked out! Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer if it helped solve the problem.